# Run docker image on amazon ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a docker image which runs with this command

```
docker run -it -p 8118:8118 -p 9050:9050 -d dperson/torproxy
```

It requires a port as an argument.

**What I tried?**

I pushed this image to ECR repo, created task related to this image. After I created service with network-load-balancer. But the server is not responding when I try to GET `DNS name` of `network-load-balancer`.

I think this is because I didn't configure the port for the container.
How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Comment: The **port mappings** are configured in the Container section of the Task Definition.

Comment: @MattD So when i create a task it will call 'docker run -p <port>' under the hood with port i configured in **port mappings**?

Comment: Something like that, yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port Mappings are part of the Task Definition > Container Definitions.

This can be done through the UI [Add Container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#standard_container_definition_params) or using the [CLI / SDK RegisterTaskDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterTaskDefinition.html)

```
{
   "containerDefinitions": [ 
      { 
         ...
         "portMappings": [ 
            { 
               "containerPort": number,
               "hostPort": number,
               "protocol": "string"
            }
         ],
         ...
      }
   ]      
}
```